# Integrating Monkeyrunner with UI Automator

Tags: android, ui-automation, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

Is it possible to integrate monkey runner with UI Automator. I have imported the Monkeyrunner jar in UI Automator project.But when I run

```
ant build
```

Build Fails as it does not recognise any of the Classes.
Is their any other method to recognise Monkeyrunner classes in UI Automator Java Project

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

[AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) supports UiAutomator if present in the device.

The details can be seen on this post: http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2012/11/androidviewclient-uiautomator-support.html

Comment: Does AndroidViewClient wrap around UIAutomator or does it connect to the UIAutomator backend running on the device?  I'm kinda confused by the lack of documentation for both.