# Is it possible to run MonkeyRunner tests, when UIAutomator is running on the Device?

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-uiautomator

I have an app running based on UIAutomator. Is is possible to test the same with MonkeyRunner or any other tools?

Comment: As per MonkeyRunner documentation, you can install an application, send keystrokes and take and store screenshots. You can go through this link http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html

Comment: Duplicated question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099071/integrating-monkeyrunner-with-ui-automator

Comment: No its not a duplicate question. The question is testing the UIAutomator test case, not working along with it. Exception is thrown while starting monkey runner or any existing framework, when UIAutomator is already running. I end up writing the events directly to the Android internal IO files, like adb sendevent does internally.